# C# GetName() , GetArea() for custom class "Shape" and it's derived classes

Tags: c#

I have a task :

There is an hierarchy: "Shape" - base class, "Triangle", "Circle", "Rectangle" - derived classes of "Shape", "IsoscelesTriangle" - derived class of "Triangle", "Square" - derived class of "Rectangle". "Shape" has methods: GetArea() - returns the area of a geometric shape, GetName() - returns the name of a geometric shape. For each derived class area and name can be determined. Console program demonstrates the principle of polymorphism using the output messages of name and area.

so at this moment my main looks like this:

```
        Problem1_1.Shape triangle1 = new Problem1_1.Triangle("triangle1", 5, 10);
        double triangle1Area = triangle1.GetArea();
        string triangle1Name = triangle1.GetName();
        Console.WriteLine(triangle1Name, triangle1Area);

        Problem1_1.Shape isoTriangle1 = new Problem1_1.IsoscelesTriangle("iso triangle", 2, 10);
        double isoTriangle1Area = isoTriangle1.GetArea();
        string isoTriangle1Name = isoTriangle1.GetName();
        Console.WriteLine(isoTriangle1Name, isoTriangle1Area);

        Problem1_1.Shape circle1 = new Problem1_1.Circle("circle1", 5);
        double circle1Area = circle1.GetArea();
        string circle1Name = circle1.GetName();
        Console.WriteLine(circle1Name, circle1Area);

        Problem1_1.Shape rect1 = new Problem1_1.Rectangle("rectangle1", 2, 10);
        double rect1Area = rect1.GetArea();
        string rect1Name = rect1.GetName();
        Console.WriteLine(rect1Name, rect1Area);

        Problem1_1.Shape square1 = new Problem1_1.Square("sq1", 2, 3);
        double square1Area = square1.GetArea();
        string square1Name = square1.GetName();
        Console.WriteLine(square1Name, square1Area);
```

my custom classes namespace looks like this:

```
namespace Problem1_1
{
    public abstract class Shape
{
    protected Shape(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; }

    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return "Shape: " + Name;
    }

    public abstract double GetArea();

}

public class Triangle : Shape
{
    private double side;
    private double height;

    public Triangle(string name, double side, double height) : base (name)
    {
        this.side = side;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public override double GetArea()
    {
        double area = (side * height) / 2;
        return area;
    }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    private double radius;

    public Circle(string name, double radius) : base (name)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public override double GetArea()
    {
        double area = radius * radius * Math.PI;
        return area;
    }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    private double side1;
    private double side2;

    public Rectangle(string name, double side1, double side2) : base (name)
    {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
    }

    public override double GetArea()
    {
        double area = side1 * side2;
        return area;
    }
}

public class IsoscelesTriangle : Triangle
{

    public IsoscelesTriangle(string name, double side, double height) : base (name, side, height) { }

    public override double GetArea()
    {
        return base.GetArea();
    }
}

public class Square : Rectangle
{
    private double side1;

    public Square(string name, double side1, double side2) : base(name, side1, side2)
    {
        this.side1 = side1;
    }


    public override double GetArea()
    {
        double area = side1 * side1;
        return area;
    }
}
}
```

so what r the issues.

First, my console message doesn't give me the area. It gives me only the name. What should I change to get both?

Second, I don't know how to handle the Square class. If it is derived from rectangle how can I get only 1 value to calculate area. If I set it like this :

```
public Square(string name, double side1) : base(name, side1)
```

I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you pass two values for the side of a Square in its constructor? You just need one side to define a Square.

```
Problem1_1.Shape square1 = new Problem1_1.Square("sq1", 2);
double square1Area = square1.GetArea();
string square1Name = square1.GetName();
Console.WriteLine($"Name={square1Name}, Area={square1Area}");
```

Then change the constructor of Square to be

```
public class Square : Rectangle
{
    private double side1;

    public Square(string name, double side1) : base(name, side1, side1)
    {
        this.side1 = side1;
    }
}
```

As you can see, you could also remove the override for GetArea and let the base class of Square (Rectangle) return its calculations.

I suggest also to make the two side variables inside the Rectangle class *protected* so you can also remove the variable side1 inside the Square class

```
public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    protected double side1;
    protected double side2;
    ...
}
```

Finally, for the output problem, you just need to use Console.WriteLine correctly as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no overload of Conosole.WriteLine(); which allows you to print two or more varialble like that, you need to use formatting like,
Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", triangleName, triangleArea);
Console.WriteLine($"{triangle1Name} : {triangle1Area}");

And can you explain second question a little more?

Comment: the answer below is the answer to my second question. thx for the tip for console.writeline . this was the first time we used console to output any msg.